# how can I use same XML layout for different activities?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to android development.I want to use same layout file for two different activities.here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ToggleButton toggleButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toggleButton=findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
  
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

               on();
            } 
        }
    });
}
public void on()
{

    Toast.makeText(this, "button on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
}
```

second activity

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
ToggleButton toggleButton;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view);
toggleButton=findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                textView.setText("hello MainActivity2");
            } 
        }
    });
}
}
```

My layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here no text is coming on if i checked the button only toast is coming.
I am searching for an answer to this.
I dont know how to use this. any type of help will be useful.

Comment: use include in xml

Comment: Probably a nullpointer exception . in `MainActivity2` your `toggleButton` is null because u never initialized it .

Comment: @ADM I just tried nothing happend

Comment: set some background to your `TextView` and inspect is it even visible at all (placed on screen) or only text is invisible

Comment: @snachmsm yes I put text from xml there with some background..it is visible

Comment: try to call `textView.invalidate()` or `textView.requestLayout()` after setting text

Comment: @snachmsm tried..nothing changes...anything else?

Answer (score 0):

### The issue

---

You are providing the constraints for the views which overlap each other. This way, they do not get visible. You must change your layout or constraint the views in different way. I will give solution for changing the layout.

### The solution

---

Try this code in your xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Tried this code in XML...nothing changes same result

Comment: It happens in both the activities or only one?

Comment: see I am printing text in one activity and toast in other activity. here I am getting only Toast and text is not printing. If I use only one activity for this ...it will done but I want to do it using two activities for one xml layout

Comment: is the `onCheckedChanged` being called? Try to add a log there and see if the app reaches there. Or best, just debug it

Answer (score 0):

Another issue might be occurring. Let me explain it here.

You are only setting the text when the button is checked. Not when it is not checked. Try to. display different text every time it's checked or not. Try this code in second activity:

```java
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
ToggleButton toggleButton;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view);
toggleButton=findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                textView.setText("hello MainActivity2");
            } else {
                textView.setText("bye MainActivity2");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: tried..no change

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595147/17133283) link

Comment: at starting i tried using that link only..did not got what i want...well thanks for your time

Comment: `did not got what i want..` what does not work as expected

Comment: I am doing the same way as it in the link given by you

Comment: so what is not working? Same issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243817/discussion-between-akshay-and-sambhav-k).